# Adding cost tag data to S3 presigned form data in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, tags

I have a working PHP code that generates signed form data that my JS app uses to upload a file to S3. Everything works fine.

What I want now is to automatically add a cost tag to the uploaded file. I've added this x-amz-tagging field but it's not working, and can't find any sample code to do this.

I hope someone can point me on the right direction. Here's my code:

```
$formInputs = [
            'acl' => 'private',
            'Content-Type' => $type,
            'key' => "company_{$idCompany}/$s3Filename",
            'x-amz-tagging' => "origen={$companyName}"];

$options = [
            ['bucket' => self::S3_BUCKET],
            ['acl' => 'private'],
            ['Content-Type' => $type],          
            ['starts-with', '$key', "company_{$idCompany}/"],
            ['starts-with', '$x-amz-tagging', "origen={$companyName}"]];

$expires = '+1 hours';

$postObject = new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4($s3Client, self::S3_BUCKET, $formInputs, $options, $expires);
```

Update: I am able to set the tag on the object using the `putObjectTagging` function after it has been uploaded, so I don't think there is any permission issues here.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps are needed for this to work:

- Use `Tagging` instead of `x-amz-tagging`
- Use the encoding scheme specified in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

Here is the final working code:

```
$formInputs = [
    'acl' => 'private',
    'Content-Type' => $type,
    'key' => "company_{$idCompany}/$s3Filename",
    'Tagging' => "<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>origen</Key><Value>{$companyName}</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>"];

$options = [
  ['bucket' => self::S3_BUCKET],
  ['acl' => 'private'],
  ['Content-Type' => $type],
  ['starts-with', '$key', "company_{$idCompany}/"],
  ['eq', '$Tagging', "<Tagging><TagSet><Tag><Key>origen</Key><Value>{$companyName}</Value></Tag></TagSet></Tagging>"]];

$expires = '+1 hours';

$postObject = new \Aws\S3\PostObjectV4($s3Client, self::S3_BUCKET, $formInputs, $options, $expires);
```

Update: an Amazon sales rep confirmed me that cost tags **only work at bucket level, not object level**, so if your app needs to split S3 costs amongst multiple customers you must create a bucket for each customer and tag the bucket.